# Patch/mock function inside another function for testing in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

Basically I'd like to patch functions that another function calls so that I can confirm they've been called. Is this possible in js? (I'm using Mocha/Chai/Sinon for testing).

A simplified version of what I'd like to do:

```
// in render.js
export helper = function() {}
export default = function() {
  helper()
}

// in the render-test.js
import render, { helper } from 'render'
// what I'd like to to:
helper = sinon.spy()
render()
assert(helper.called, true)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible, but it does require some rewriting, most notably the way you're calling `helper` in `render.js`.

Here's an example that works:

```
// render.js
export function helper() {}
export default function() {
  exports.helper()
}

// render-test.js
import render, * as renderFuncs from 'render'
...
sinon.spy(renderFuncs, 'helper');
render()
assert(renderFuncs.helper.called)
```

The reason you need to call `exports.helper()` instead of just `helper()` is because the latter is a *local* reference to the `helper` function, which you can't access from the test file.

The `exports` object *is* accessible from the test file (it's given the name `renderFuncs`), so Sinon can change the reference to `helper` and wrap it with a spy.